# Filter null values after map in Java 8

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I'm new in using `map` and `filters` in Java 8. I'm currently using `Spark ML` library for some ML algorithms. 
I have the following code:

```
// return a list of `Points`.
List<Points> points = getPoints();
List<LabeledPoint> labeledPoints = points.stream()
                                        .map(point -> getLabeledPoint(point))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The function `getLabeledPoint(Point point)` returns a new `LabeledPoint` if the data is correct or null otherwise. How can I filter (remove) the `null` `LabeledPoint` objects after `map`?

Answer (score 39):

There is [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method on Stream:

```
// return a list of `Points`.
List<Points> points = getPoints();
List<LabeledPoint> labeledPoints = points.stream()
                                    .map(point -> getLabeledPoint(point))
                                    // NOTE the following:
                                    .filter(e -> e != null)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: also you can use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`